# Ограничение масштабирования matrix.ScaleAt()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Всем привет. Подскажите, как задать максимум и  минимум при масштабировании.

```
<UserControl
... 
Height="1000" Width="1000" ManipulationStarting="uc_ManipulationStarting" ManipulationDelta="uc_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationInertiaStarting="uc_ManipulationInertiaStarting" ManipulationCompleted="uc_ManipulationCompleted">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <MatrixTransform x:Key="InitialMatrixTransform">
            <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                <Matrix OffsetX="-200" OffsetY="-80"/>
            </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
        </MatrixTransform>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Canvas Background="Gray" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Grid Name="manGrid" Width="1920" Height="1080" RenderTransform="{StaticResource InitialMatrixTransform}" IsManipulationEnabled="true">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="..."/>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

-

```
private void uc_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e) {
    e.ManipulationContainer = this;
}
private void uc_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e) {
    // Get the Grid and its RenderTransform matrix.
    Grid gridToMove = e.OriginalSource as Grid;
    Matrix gridsMatrix = ((MatrixTransform) gridToMove.RenderTransform).Matrix;

    // Resize the Grid.  Keep it square 
    // so use only the X value of Scale.
    gridsMatrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
    e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
    e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
    e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

    // Apply the changes to the Grid.
    gridToMove.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(gridsMatrix);
}
```

Comment: @dex, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

MaxHeight и MaxWidth - максимум
MinHeight и MinWidth - минимум

Comment: RenderTransform не влияет на реальный размер содержимого контейнера manGrid